# Removing Windows XP after installing Ubuntu by liveCD netinstall

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, uninstall, windows-xp

I'm new to linux OS so forgive my noobiness.

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my Windows XP computer as a dual partition using the netinstall mini.iso burned to a cd-r. I had issues with unity desktop running slow so I installed the Xubuntu desktop, everything runs great, I love it and now I want to completely remove all traces of Windows XP and have Xubuntu take over the 50GB of space Windows is currently occupying.

I read in another post that I can go to Settings-Disks, choose the Windows partition and delete it using the - button, then remove the grub so it removes the option for XP at startup.

My question then is, will this then give Xubuntu that 50GB to use or do I have to do this another way?

Any help appreciated, I want my 50GB back lol

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a link of a gparted screenshot. It is easy to remove Windows, but with that information we will help you to do it the best way.

Comment: Don't remove GRUB! Run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal instead. that should do the trick. Then you can enlarge your partition with gparted, but if your XP partition was before/on the left of the Ubuntu partition, you have to do this from a live system (boot from a CD or USB media).

Comment: Thanks for your comments,  followed used Gparted and the issue is solved :)